# Azure SQL delete performance is much slower than local SQL-Express Server

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-delete, sql-execution-plan

### The problem

I am using "Windows Azure SQL Database" and have following behavior. 
A delete statement (2000 rows) need some seconds on my local machine. On the azure sql database it needs over 2 minutes.

After some search i found that the query execution plan of a deletion is different in azure and on my local machine.

Performing my query on both databases, i get completely different query execution plans.

### The query

The query which is slow in the Azure database is:

```
DELETE BaseObjects WHERE Id=134510
```

### Execution plans

Query on local machine:

[image: local database]

Query on azure database:

[image: azure database]

### Configuration

There are no special configuration on both databases, both databases have the default configuration.
I am using a azure sql database "Standard S3: 100 DTUs". Its DTU-based not vCore-based. There is an Index for the "Id" column.

#### Why is that query execution plan so big?

#### Could that be a performance problem on my side?

#### How can I improve the performance for this statement?

Comment: can you post how your index is configured? The query plans looks like it's updating the index on deletion

Comment: I have 4 indexes (1 primary key and 3 non-clustered) on the baseobject table and 6 foreign keys referencing to the baseobject table. I can't post the whole ERD for security reasons

Comment: is the setup the same in your local db? doesn't look like it when I look at your query plan. Hence, you cannot really compare the two, can you?

Comment: The database model is the same. The local database is a backup from the azure database. The configurations of the database server are default, we changed nothing on the local and on the azure.

Comment: That looks like a cascading delete.  Is it supposed to be?